# Why does the following lines of code not adding anything to the array and the array just produces null

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Why does the following lines of code not adding anything to the `array` and the `array` just produces `null`.

```
 NSString *LIstringURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.staticflickr.com/%@/%@_%@.jpg",flickrfarmID,flickrServer, flickrID,flickrSecret];

    NSString *SIstringURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.staticflickr.com/%@/%@_%@_t.jpg",flickrfarmID,flickrServer, flickrID,flickrSecret];

    // NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:stringURL];
    NSArray *bothImagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:LIstringURL,SIstringURL, nil];
    [self.urlArray addObject:bothImagesArray];
```

Comment: Have you allocated and initialized `self.urlArray`?

Comment: Where do you detect that array "produces null"?

Comment: I use breakpoints and NSLog just after that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the mutable array is initiated or not

```
self.urlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: If ARC is not being used then that will cause a leak.

Comment: if the question doesnt specify that its using MRC then its pretty safe to assume ARC is being used...

Comment: In my experience that isn't true.

Comment: First, the question's sample code indicates that ARC is being used. And even if not, that code alone will not cause a leak. And this question is not about memory management. Not at all.

Comment: @HermannKlecker It's not obvious to someone coming to this question that ARC is being used or not, so I would suggest that this answer either clarifies that it's for ARC or that it provides implementations for both ARC and MRR.  Also that code alone will cause a leak.

Comment: Well, yes, "that code ALONE" will cause a leak unless ARC is used. And of course unless the allocated object is being relesed one way or the other. But that is off topic here!

Comment: @HermannKlecker If someone provides code showing how to allocate and initialize an array, and under some circumstances that code causes a leak, then it should be discussed, and so it's not off topic.  I don't understand why the answerer is unwilling to provide more detail with his answer and put an end to this pointless discussion.

Comment: I stop this fruitless and nerdy discussion here, because I do not think this helps my Bavarian friend here. The key point is that he may not have initialized his mutable array. We do not see the initialization and if he really did not allocate or initialize it properly then that may well have lead to the symptoms he describes. And Nazik pointet out that very well without distracting user1898829 with any off topic background noise. That's worth an upvote.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Yeah I know that; that's why I asked him in a comment before NAZIK posted his speculative answer.  However the OP seems uninterested in any answer anyway, given he has not returned to his question, so there is nothing to distract.

Comment: I'm using ARC. Will include that in all future questions. I'm from South Africa and not from Bavaria, despite my Bavarian name.